# Export SAS dataset in Excel's "Text (MS-DOS)" format

Tags: sas, csv

I need to export a data set as text file for an ancient batch process probably running on Unix. The file has one column and all fields are numeric.

I want to create a text file which emulates the way Excel creates **Text (MS-DOS)** files:

> Saves a workbook as a tab-delimited text file for use on the MS-DOS
>   operating system, and ensures that tab characters, line breaks, and
>   other characters are interpreted correctly. Saves only the active
>   sheet.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: MS-DOS?! You mean the Microsoft Operating System that was superseded by Windows 95, 21 years ago?

Comment: I believe an ancient batch process  is picking up this file. Sorry I don't know if it is msdos, probably Unix.

Comment: I just need the file to come out the same way as Excel would export

Comment: If you only have one column then the delimiter does not matter.

Comment: You should find out what the actual requirements are of the process that consumes the data. In particular if it's not actually running on MS-DOS it's unlikely it would expect it to use the MS-DOS specific code page 437.

Answer (score 2):

[DOS uses encoding page 437](http://excelribbon.tips.net/T009508_Comma-Delimited_and_MS-DOS_CSV_Variations.html), which is a very limited set of characters. If you don't have any special characters, you're good. If you do have special characters, you'll need to change the encoding page to [437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) in order to guarantee character compatibility. This can be done as a `dataset` option.

[SAS internally names this `pcoem437`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/nlsref/61893/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002607278.htm). You can see the difference in output by changing the `encoding=` option.

```
data have;
    input var$;
    datalines;
ElNiño
ElNino
;
run;

proc export data=have(encoding=pcoem437)
            file='C:\Directory\want.txt'
            dbms=tab 
            replace;
run;
```

Comment: What about carriage returns and line feeds? Which one should be used?

Comment: In hex, carriage return will be '0D', and line feed will be '0A'. You should use whichever encoding option is compatible with your system.

Answer (score 1):

If you just have one column then the delimiter doesn't matter. You can write the file using a DATA step very easily.

```
data _null_;
   set have ;
   file 'myfile.txt' ;
   put VAR1 ;
run;
```

If you want to add an extra line with the column name then add this before the PUT statement.

```
  if _n_=1 then put 'VAR1';
```

If you are worried about whether you need to generate LF or CRLF for the end of line you can control that with the `TERMSTR=` option on the FILE statement.